# Java for loop optimization - Storing getters before the loop

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, compiler-optimization, callstack

Suppose you have the following code..

```
for(Element elm : elements)
   if(elm instanceof Foobar)
      Session.getSomething().getListOfSomething().add((Foobar)elm);
```

Would it not be better to do the following?

```
List<Foobar> list = Session.getSomething().getListOfSomething();

for(Element elm : elements)
   if(elm instanceof Foobar)
      list.add((Foobar)elm);
```

Assuming that Something and listOfSomething do not change during the execution of the loop.
I am thinking this could greatly cut down on the number of callstack push/pops due to reduced method calls.

Is this type of optimization being too nitpicky? I don't think java compilers would assume they could optimize this way.

**EDIT : Unsimplified the code to exclude usage of AddAll**

Comment: why not `Session.getSomething().getListOfSomething().addAll(elements)`?

Comment: Before anything, have you seen the bytecode generated in both cases?

Comment: `I don't think java compilers would assume they could optimize this way.`, why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a good deal of compilers DO assume they can optimize that way.

Comment: @GuillermoRenéRamírez Not in Java. Only if the methods are final and returning const values.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Out of curiosity, why the `final` requirement?

Comment: @GuillermoRenéRamírez It means it can be called as non-virtual function, so its a good candidate for inlining during code generation phase. I.e. if the function is final, or private, or the whole class is final or private, the compiler can make considerably more assumptions without breaking the Java conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better in most cases. The reason is that Java is pretty strict on calling conventions, and for every iteration it will have to make 4 extra virtual calls. There are some exceptions (i.e. inlining by JIT), but that is an exotic.

Though it might be even better to use default function:

```
Session.getSomething().getListOfSomething().addAll(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on what `getSomething()` and `getListOfSomething()` do. The reason it may not be optimized is that the compiler doesn't know whether the call is going to return the same thing every time, or whether there are other side effects of calling those methods. If it does return the same thing every time, with no side effects, then yes it is an optimization, if it doesn't then it is no longer even the same program.